# what is the key difference between multipaxos and basic paxos protocol

Tags: operating-system, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, paxos

how is multipaxos different from basic paxos? How does ordering work in multipaxos?
Can someone explain  multi-paxos along with the diagram

Tried out going through videos and research papers but cannot understand the exact difference and concept of multi paxos

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26619261/329496

Comment: And here is a description of a practical implementation of (multi) paxos that i wrote that explains how it can work https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/transaction-log-replication-with-paxos/#more-557

Comment: And finally, the original two papers talk about having a stable leader which is the practical application of the original to page as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012211/329496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic paxos allows a set of nodes to agree on a value. After the consensus is reached, the value will never changes. The fact that the value will never change is a serious limitation where paxos can be applied. Strictly speaking, when a consensus is reached, then each acceptor will have a tuple `[N, V]`, where `N` is identifier number and `V` is the value agreed on.

In most practical tasks, consensus needs to be reached on and on. For example, we could use paxos for transaction management in a bank. So for every transaction will require a new consensus. Single paxos clearly won't work as it can't change consensus value at all.

So if one has several cases where a consensus is needed, one of options would be to just run paxos several times, independently for each case. This will lead to two problems: a) ordering of events and b) optimizations.

Independent rounds of paxes won't help with ordering. Since every paxos instance agrees independently on `[N, V]`, there is nothing there to decide which of those events happened first. `N` is paxos's identifier number won't help as it varies for each instance.

This is where multipaxos comes in - if there is a stream of values to agree on and there is a stable proposer, then we can do two things - add ordering and optimize the flow.

Optimization comes from the fact that the leader is more or less stable. It knows the last successful identifier number `N` and knows that its proposals will be accepted with high probability (till another leader emerges). This observation removes several messages in the protocol, the leader can keep sending `Accepts` without `Prepare` - big optimization.

Order is managed in multipaxos by adding another counter `I`, which is get incremented by the leader for every new value. So when there is a consensus, it is reached on tuple of `[I, N, V]` (instead of single paxos with `[N, V]`).

To clarify: `I` is the value for events ordering, it is incremented by the leader every time when a value is agreed on. This implies that the leader is a learner as well (doesn't have to be, but this is a common approach).

Eventually, multipaxos is about optimizing consensus on a stream of values.

p.s.
as for a diagram, wikipedia has a good one, putting the link instead of copying that over: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)#Multi-Paxos_when_roles_are_collapsed